# C# Richtext box MouseOver

Tags: c#, richtextbox

How to get the `MouseOver` text in a `RichTextBox`.
I have tried using `GetCharIndexFromPosition` by passing it the cursor location. But it is always giving me the index of a character which is close to the mouse location, even if I am moving the mouse onto the `RichTextBox` (empty space) it is giving some character index which is closer to the mouse location.

Comment: Have you tried to get then GetPositionFromCharIndex and to compare with actual mouse position? the problem here is how to calculate a char size to understand whether your mouse cursor is really inside that area

Comment: Thanks username. I am able to solve the problem. As you said am comparing the position from char index and actual mouse position. Calculating charcter size using rich text box graphics and adding it to the position of character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks username. I am able to solve the problem. As you said am comparing the position from char index and actual mouse position. Calculating charcter size using rich text box graphics and adding it to the position of character.